# Progress ABL procedure to SQL Insert

Tags: progress-4gl

We have a software solution that involves syncing some data between a Progress database and SQL server. Unfortunately, we do not have any Progress gurus in house, so I'm working kinda blind here and would welcome any advice that is on offer.

For the workflow that is already in place, what would work very well for us is the ability to do an external call to insert a row into an SQL database from an within ABL procedure's 'for each' loop.

Is anyone able to direct me to any code snippets or articles that might help me achieve this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your SQL database is MS SQL Server, you might want to have a look at OpenEdge DataServer for Microsoft SQL Server ([web.progress.com/en/openedge/dataserver-microsoft.html](http://web.progress.com/en/openedge/dataserver-microsoft.html), [documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dmsql/dmsql.pdf](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dmsql/dmsql.pdf)).

The DataServer provides you with ABL access to a non-Progress database so you can use standard Progress statements, e.g. CREATE to add new records or FOR EACH to retrieve query results.

OpenEdge DataServers are also available for Oracle (using Oracle Call Interface), DB2 and Sybase (using ODBC). The DataServer for MS SQL Server uses ODBC behind the scenes as well. [web.progress.com/docs/datasheets/openedge/openedge_dataservers.pdf](http://web.progress.com/docs/datasheets/openedge/openedge_dataservers.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the dataserver, connection with ADODB works fine in ABL, you can even call stored-procedures with the command object, the user you connect with will have to be granted EXEC rigths on the SQL-Server to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Progress guru, but I did do some work in it for awhile. AFAIK there is no way to have ABL code connect to a non-Progress database (part of that whole vendor lock-in strategy Progress Corp. leverages).

Your best bet is probably to have the ABL code serialize the records to XML, and use something like [ActiveMQ](http://code.google.com/p/abl2stomp/) (or even a plain socket or named pipe/FIFO depending on your setup) to send them to a program written in a more capable language to do the SQL insert.

Comment: Progress "data servers" are used to connect to foreign databases.